# Swift: Why am I not getting an array from my NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary instantiated like this:

```
var organizedUsers = [String: [User]]()
```

Where User is my own custom class. This should be easy to get the array of users for a particular string, right?

However, when I try to get the array, I end up getting an entire dictionary! Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
var sortedKeys = [String]()
sortedKeys = Array(organizedUsers.keys)
organizedUsers[sortedKeys[section]!].count //This line has an error
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And where does `section` come from?

Comment: The second statement assignment discards the Array created on the line above. You probably just want to declare the type, not create an instance.

Comment: It is generally easier to debug and find errors if each statement does less. There is nothing to be gained by avoiding intermediate statements and  variables.

Comment: To be more accurate, you're not creating an `NSDictionary`, you're creating a Swift `Dictionary`, which is toll-free bridged to an `NSDictionary`, but is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your line:

```
organizedUsers[sortedKeys[section]!].count
```

to

```
organizedUsers[sortedKeys[section]]!.count
```

to can access to the `count` property assuming that `section` is `Int` of course to can index over the array, see the following example:

```
struct User {
   var name: String
}

var organizedUsers = [String: [User]]()
organizedUsers["User"] = [User(name: "Victor")]

var sortedKeys = [String]()
sortedKeys = Array(organizedUsers.keys) // ["User"]
organizedUsers[sortedKeys[0]]!.count // 1
```